# how to handle the Click button event in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Asp.net MVC and developing an application having a form with 2 textboxes for input and 1 for output.I have added the buttons in the form as well.Now i want to display the output 
in the output textbox on click button event. Please let me know how can i do that in MVC4.

Comment: Please, before posting, have a look at the [asp.net MVC tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info) and follow the docs and tutorial references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button Event in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722935/button-event-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC does not work the same as ASP.NET WebForms. Or rather, I should say ASP.NET WebForms does not work the same as the rest of the web(!).

When you create an HTML form is has an `action` attribute that specifies the URL that should handle the form submission. When the user submits the form, through an `input` or `button` with `type="submit"`, the browser does a `POST` request to that URL, including the data contained in the form through using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type by default (different if the form should include file upload).

Your server-side code should not be responding to individual UI events as this is not how the web works, WebForms merely gave you an abstraction over HTTP to lure you into a sense of control that does not exist on the web.

Here is two example action methods that would handle the `GET` and `POST` requests for the form:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyFormFields();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyFormFields fields)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(fields);
    }

    // do stuff with form data

    var model = new MyResultModel
    {
         Output = fields.Input // for e.g.
    };

    return View("Results", model);
}
```

This responds to the form submission and renders a different view with the results view model. Best practice suggests doing an HTTP redirect here such that the browser can't resubmit the `POST` request by accident, but we'll leave that for later.